# Using FME to aggregate POI to one point

Tags: fme-form, clustering, aggregation, grouping

I want to aggregate points of interest (POI) using FME. The aggregation should make it possible to group all POI within an area based on a buffer distance from the centerpoint of n POI.

This would mean an iterative approach where all POI are subject to a buffer-select analysis counting the number of POI within the bufffer distance. The most "clusteder" POIs will then be used to represent a combination related to the POI types.

If possible the attributes from all POI should be merged so that all atttributes from all aggregated POI are kept as separate attributes in the representative POI.

The procedure is straightforward, but can this be done using FME?

This question is related to my question [Group and align icons in QGIS atlas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185599/group-and-align-icons-in-qgis-atlas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear as to what you're actually trying to do.  But I'm going to go ahead and say that it is almost certainly possible to achieve in FME.

There are a number of transformers available in FME that could help you with your task.  Firstly, there is the **[NeighborFinder](https://www.safe.com/transformers/neighbor-finder/)**. You can use this to find features which are close to each other.

> Finds the Candidate features closest to each Base feature and merges
>   their attributes onto the Base feature according to the Accumulation
>   Mode parameter. Or, if Input is set to Candidates Only, performs the
>   same operation using each Candidate as a Base feature, considering all
>   other Candidates, but not itself.

There is also the **[Snapper](https://www.safe.com/transformers/snapper/)** transformer and the **[AnchoredSnapper](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/anchoredsnapper.htm)** transformer to snap the points to a particular position.

From the Snapper Documentation:

> Brings lines, segments, end points or vertex points of features
>   together if they are within a certain distance of each other and
>   (optionally) if they have one or more attributes in common.

From the AnchoredSnapper Documentation:

> Takes a series of features that match the input specification and
>   performs snapping on the features that lie within the specified
>   tolerance from other features that match the input specification. You
>   can use this transformer to perform cleaning operations on data during
>   a translation.

Also, you will probably want to use the **[FeatureMerger](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/featuremerger.htm)**.

From the FeatureMerger Documentation:

> Copies and merges the attributes/geometry from one feature (or
>   multiple features) onto another feature (or multiple features).

There are many other transformers that may help with your task, depending on how you want to tackle the problem.  But these should steer you on the right track.  There are also pages which discuss clustering methods in FME. Such as [**here**](https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/24064/cluster-points-based-on-location-k-means-method.html), **[here](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/1258/cluster-or-density-modelling.html)**, and **[here](https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/5155/segmentationclustering-of-features-based-on-attrib.html)**.

Hope this helps...