# How to include aggregate field values of clustered points

Tags: postgis, postgresql, aggregation

I am creating a map that has point features representing things like campgrounds, picnic areas, boat launches, etc.  In cases where many points are clustered in an area (representing amenities for the same park or campground), I'd like to create a single point that includes the values of each point in the cluster, so that I can symbolize it as described in [Group and align icons in QGIS atlas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185599/group-and-align-icons-in-qgis-atlas).

I created the centroid of the point cluster using ST_ClusterWithin() described in [Spatial clustering with PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11567/spatial-clustering-with-postgis).

The [string_agg function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) mentioned in [How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'group by' query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query) seems to fit the bill for aggregating the "amenity" field values.  However, I need to "group by" the spatial cluster of points, not tabular values.

Conceptually, it would look something like below, but the values returned in agg_amenity would be grouped by the points each cluster.  Right now, it just aggregates values from all points.  Concept code is below:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER () AS gid,
    f.agg_amenity,
    ST_NumGeometries(f.gc) AS numgeom,
    ST_Centroid(f.gc) AS geom
   FROM ( SELECT string_agg(table.amenity, ';') AS agg_amenity,
            unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(table.geom, 250)) AS gc
           FROM table) f;
```

The input looks something like:

> ```
> | gid | name   | site_name      | amenity    | geom  |
> | 1   | Park A | park camground | campground | point |
> | 2   | Park A | park picnic    | picnic     | point |
> | 3   | Park A | park swim      | swimming   | point |
> | 4   | Park B | park camground | campground | point |
> | 5   | Park B | park camground | groupsite  | point |
> ```

And the output should look like this:

> ```
> | gid | name   | amenity                        | geom                        |
> | 101 | Park A | 'campground, picnic, swimming' | point (centroid of cluster) |
> | 102 | Park B | 'campground, groupsite'        | point (centroid of cluster) |
> ```

How can I combine spatial clustering and aggregation of the amenity field (or multiple fields, if possible)?  I am using **Postgres 9.5 and PostGIS 2.2**.

Comment: Are you wanting ST_ConvexHull?  http://postgis.org/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html

Comment: I used ST_ClusterWithin() to create the centroid, now I need to aggregate the field values of only the points within the cluster.

Comment: can you provide a picture of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do this without joining the clusters back to the inputs - it's a fundamental limitation of using an aggregate.  (Similarly, the `max()` aggregate can't tell you anything else about the row where the maximum value was found.)  The solution is to use a window-based clustering function, of which some options will be available in 2.3.

Comment: @dbaston, that makes sense the way you compared it to the max() aggregate.  Do you have any alternate clustering methods you could recommend for accomplishing the task?  Or just have to wait for 2.3?

Comment: You could join the clusters back to the inputs after the fact (@raphael's answer looks like it should do the trick) or consider compiling PostGIS from source and testing the windowing functions.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a [`GROUP BY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) to specify aggregation of the rows.

```
WITH clusters AS(
    SELECT unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(table.geom, 250)) AS gc
       FROM table)
, unclustered AS( --unpacking GeomCollections
    SELECT row_number() OVER () AS cluster_id, (ST_DUMP(gc)).geom AS geom 
       FROM clusters)
SELECT cluster_id as gid, 
    string_agg(table.amenity, ';' ORDER BY table.amenity) AS agg_amenity,
    COUNT(1) AS numgeom,
    ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(geom)) AS geom
    FROM table
    INNER JOIN unclustered USING(geom)
    GROUP BY cluster_id
```

An aside, I haven't compared performance between the two functions, but I feel like [my clustering function](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/144230/36886) (also the furthest down answer on the question you linked to) produces more useful output rows `{gid, geom, and a cluster_id}` than the now built_in function. 
If you're getting multiple of the same kind of amenity within your clusters you'll want to `GROUP BY cluster_id, amenity` before aggregating.

Comment: this function gets me really close.  However, I keep getting errors when including "ORDER BY table.amenity" in the str_aggr() function.  If I remove that, it almost works.  I then an error that I need to include "unclustered.geom" in the GROUP BY clause at the end.  If I do this, the result is fine for features that share the same exact coordinates, but does not return geom for features that are clustered but do NOT share same coordinates.

Comment: @RyanDalton, I just updated, which should solve your issues

Comment: Thanks for trying to update.  It's having trouble on "ST_Centroid(gc) AS geom".  I tried changing the field to "clusters.gc", but no luck.

Comment: @RyanDalton My bad, didn't realize ST_ClusterWithin returned an array, hence needing the `unnest` call in the `clusters` CTE. That should now have ST_Centroid acting on geomcollections

Comment: @raphael I don't understand `unnest(gc)` in `unclustered` table. gc is not an array so you can't make an unnest() on it.

Comment: @NicolasBoisteault good catch! I was thinking that the Geometry_Collections needed to be unpacked but wasn't fully thinking through what function that should be. Updating based on this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/195444/36886

Comment: @raphael I found another issue. `row_number() OVER ()` return 1 for every line, I think it is because of `unnest` behavior. So you have to make `SELECT row_number() OVER () AS cluster_id,temp.gc from (
    select unnest(ST_ClusterWithin(table.the_geom, 2000)) AS gc
       FROM gods.v_export_n79_cleaned) temp` instead.

Comment: Good catch! I just updated and moved it to the second CTE, since it has the same problem with ST_Dump, which is fine.